# jQuery find and replace text based on key value pair object

Tags: jquery, arrays, search, object, replace

i've rummaged around and found some useful posts for doing find / search / replace in jquery using a key value pair array / object,

but i can't get it to work,

here's the site's test URL:

http://www.larryadowns.com.php5-1.dfw1-2.websitetestlink.com/

as you can see, it's a blog feed with post info. i'm trying to target the date months, and do a search and replace for each to put in the spanish months.

here's the javascript, it's all wrapped in a jQuery(document).ready()...

```
    var monthMap = {
        "January" : "Enero",
        "February" : "Febrero",
        "March" : "Marzo",
        "April" : "Abril",
        "May" : "Mayo",
        "June" : "Junio",
        "July" : "Julio",
        "August" : "Agosto",
        "September" : "Septiembre",
        "October" : "Octubre",
        "November" : "Noviembre",
        "December" : "Diciembre"
    };

    // sift thru the post-info, replacing only the month with the spanish one.
    $(".post-info .date").text(function(index, originalText) {

        var moddedText = '';

        for ( var month in monthMap ) {

            if (!monthMap.hasOwnProperty(month)) {
                continue;
            }

            moddedText = originalText.replace(month, monthMap[month]);

//            moddedText = originalText.replace( new RegExp(month, "g") , monthMap[month] );

            console.log("month : " + month);
            console.log("monthMap[month] : " + monthMap[month]);
        }

        console.log('-------------------');
        console.log('index : ' + index);
        console.log("monthMap : " + monthMap);
        console.log("originalText : " + originalText);

        console.log("moddedText : " + moddedText);

        return moddedText;
    });
```

but alas, neither the .replace or the .replace with the RegEx are really replacing anything.
where did i go wrong?
ty again stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure why, but it seems your code was returning the `moddedText` to it's original as it ran through subsequent months. Because of this, it was only replacing December correctly.

I've used a slightly different method but it should produce what you're looking for.

```js
$(".post-info .date").text(function(index, originalText) {

    for ( var month in monthMap )
    {
        if (originalText.indexOf(month) > -1)
        {
            return originalText.replace(month, monthMap[month]);
        }
    }

    return originalText;
});
```

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/FyWAp/1/) for full code and demo.

Comment: Most Excellent. thanks so much Goran. solved. 
it would be nice to know the why, 
if anyone ever has that answer.
but no worries.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Actually, now I've had my coffee it seems pretty obvious. Because it was iterating through all months (even after a successful match), `originalText` was overwriting the earlier successfully replaced `moddedText`. Hence why only December worked, as it has no following months.